# Prevent Decimal value rounding to a whole

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal

The below code allows a value to pass through such as "349.99" into the calculation. The only problem I have now is that the final value that gets populated in the TotalPrice text box is still rounded to the nearest whole number.

What would be the best change to make to the below code to prevent this. I am using it to calculate bill so would like to the value to be something like "239.39" etc?

Cheers
Jack

**UpdateTotalBill()**

```
    {
        long TotalPrice = 0;
        long TotalProducts = 0;
        foreach (DataListItem product in dlBasketItems.Items)
        {
            Label PriceLabel = product.FindControl("lblProductPrice") as Label;
            TextBox ProductQuantity = product.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox;

            long ProductPrice;
            {
               ProductPrice = Convert.ToInt64(PriceLabel.Text) *
                    Convert.ToInt64(ProductQuantity.Text);
            }

            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice;
            TotalProducts = TotalProducts + Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);
         }
        txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice);
        txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables are of type long, and you also use Convert.ToInt64.. that's two places where you lose you decimal part of the number.

So you should have `decimal` variables and use `Convert.ToDecimal` instead.

```
 {
            decimal TotalPrice = 0.0;
            decimal TotalProducts = 0.0;
            foreach (DataListItem product in dlBasketItems.Items)
            {
                Label PriceLabel = product.FindControl("lblProductPrice") as Label;
                TextBox ProductQuantity = product.FindControl("txtProductQuantity") as TextBox;


                decimal ProductPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceLabel.Text) *
                    Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);                    

                TotalPrice = TotalPrice + ProductPrice;
                TotalProducts = TotalProducts + Convert.ToInt32(ProductQuantity.Text);
             }
            txtTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalPrice);
            txtTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalProducts);
        }
```

In your original example, you also mix Convert.ToDecimal/Int64/Int32 for your txtproductQuantity conversion. You probably want to allow only integers to be in this field, so you can use Convert.ToInt32 only (or maybe even smaller type, depending on your numbers)